# do's and don'ts of networking for a PhD student in a conference?

Tags: conference, networking

My field is Telecommunications (Engineering). I am going to a very huge conference in our field where I am presenting my work as well. I want to take this opportunity to hone my skills of networking, make some good connections, leave some good impression of my university and myself.

I want especially to meet professors who are elite in our field (I know few that are coming) and I am not sure if they will be kind enough to give their time to me?

How should I approach these professors?

**PS.  Note that I don't expect (and don't want) to get a post-doc opportunity out of this conference, but I sure do want to make great contacts and learn skills of meeting**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One could easily make a long list of obvious don'ts relating to basic conduct at the conference.  However, given your stated goals, here are some things I would recommend:

> **Do** present your own work in a *clear and simple way* that allows the audience to understand your topic and get interested in your problem.  Be prepared to discuss your problem (and other research interests) afterwards and form collaborations if you find them useful.
>
> **Don't** try to impress people by making your talk sound complicated - make it as simple and clear as you possibly can.  Impress people by your clarity rather than trying to bamboozle them with complexity and obfuscation.
>
> **Don't** restrict your goals to meeting only the "elite" researchers.  Try to network broadly and talk to anyone else who has shared interests.  Focus on talking to people who have shared interests with you, who can have a clear and fruitful conversation with that imparts value.  You might find that your most fruitful interactions are with people closer to your own research level rather than the most elite researchers.